# Three.js dynamic waiting dialog

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've a lot of vertices and particles to draw, so when I launch the job all seems 'freezed' for some seconds. What I want to do is a dialog box where I can see step-by-step what is happening dynamically, something like:

"Rendering geometry1"

"Rendering geometry2"

"Rendering geometry3"

"Done!"

instead of a classic static message. Any suggestions to do it? I found this example (http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_scene.html) but I've not to load any external object.

Comment: Give us some example of what you are doing, maybe with a jsfiddle

Comment: When I press 'draw' button, I call a function A from where I call various other functions B, C, D.... each of which draws something in my scene. I also tried trivially to open a jQuery UI dialog when function A starts, change message inside it before B (C, D...and so on) starts with something like $("#idWaitingDialog p").text("Drawing B"), and close it when the scene is ready. But in this way I just see the first and the last message.

Comment: It is very hard to help you without seeing any of your code. Give us a jsfiddle to look at.

Comment: Ok, sorry. These are two jsfiddle versions (for convenience I replace drawing functions with something easier). As you can see in the first one I see the UI dialog only when the process is ended, in the second thanks to an ajax call I can see the dialog when the process starts but it doesn't refresh its message 'cause the browser is working.

1. http://jsfiddle.net/D3Q2w/5/

2. http://jsfiddle.net/D3Q2w/6/